# Can't pass delegate

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, anonymous-function

I've created a function that gets console input from the user as-long as it fits a filter so to speak.

```
public delegate TResult OutFunc<in T, TValue, out TResult>(T arg1, out TValue arg2);

public static T PromptForInput<T>(string prompt, OutFunc<string, T, bool> filter)
{
    T value;
    do { Console.Write(prompt); }
    while (!filter(Console.ReadLine(), out value));
    return value;
}
```

This works great when I call the method as I do below. which gets a number from the user as long as it parses to an `int` which is in the range of (0-10).

```
int num = PromptForInput("Please input an integer: ",
    delegate(string st, out int result)
    { return int.TryParse(st, out result) && result <= 10 && result >= 0; } );
```

I want to be able to re-use common filters. In multiple places in my program I want to get an `int` input from the user, so I've separated out the logic for that, and put that in its own function.

```
private bool IntFilter(string st, out int result)
{
    return int.TryParse(st, out result) && result <= 10 && result >= 0;
}
```

Now I get an error when I attempt to do this:

```
int num = PromptForInput("Please input an integer: ", IntFilter);
```

> The type arguments for method 'PromptForInput(string, OutFunc)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

How can I explicitly specify the type arguments in this case?

Comment: When lambda notation got added, the type inference rules also were made smarter.  But using those smarter rules for non-lambdas might break backward compatibility...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a generic function, and so need to declare the type:

```
int num = PromptForInput<int>("Please input an integer: ", IntFilter);
```

The compiler is just saying it can't figure that out on it's own and needs it declared explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, I just assumed the compiler could infer the type from a function symbol the same as when you give it an anonymous delegate. I don't see why it is different. But thanks, you answered my question on how to make this work.

Comment: @BenVlodgi: That could be to do with the variance you declared, perhaps, since `PromptForInput` isn't variant. I'm certainly no expert, though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [LordTakkera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1783619/lordtakkera)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22386627/1812944) I was able to also find this works as-well

```
int num = PromptForInput("Please input an integer: ", new OutFunc<string, int, bool>(IntFilter));
```

The compiler actually does this implicitly when compiling as long as you explicitly specify `PromptForInput<int>`. Though, I don't understand why the compiler can't figure this out implicitly.